# Unity in Diversity concept in ancient Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, upanishads

Bhārata Bhāgya Vidhātā (Bangali : Dispenser of the destiny of India) is a five-stanza Bramho hymn in Bengali language  [**Here**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharot_Bhagyo_Bidhata) **dedicated to Supreme divine God or Parabrahma who is the dispenser of the destiny of India.** Also this is the original hymn composed by Rabindranath Tagore for the **national anthem of India,** [**Jana Gana Mana**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_Gana_Mana).
This National anthem of India convey us the message of Unity in diversity.

Here is the text of National Anthem of India -

> जन गण मन अधिनायक जय हे, **भारत भाग्य विधाता।**  पंजाब सिन्ध गुजरात
> मराठा, द्राविड़ उत्कल बंग  विंध्य हिमाचल यमुना गंगा, उच्छल जलधि तरंग।.
> तव शुभ नामे जागे, तव शुभ आशीष मागे। गाहे तव जयगाथा  जन गण मंगलदायक जय
> हे, भारत भाग्य विधाता। जय हे, जय हे, जय हे, जय जय जय जय हे॥
>
> Jana gaṅa mana-adhināẏyaka jaya hē **Bhāratabhāgyavidhātā**! Pañjāba
> Sindhu Gujarāta Marāthā Drāvida Utkala Baṅga Vindhya Himācala Yamunā
> Gaṅgā ucchalajaladhitaraṅga Taba śubha nāmē jāgē, taba śubha āśiṣa
> māgē, Gāhē taba jayaẏagāthā. Jana gaṅaṇamaṅgaladāẏaka jaya hē
> Bhāratabhāgyavidhātā! Jaya hē, jaya hē, jaya hē, jaya jaya jaya jaya
> hē..

My question is - **Are there any similar Verses ,text, quotes written in ancient Hinduism literature like Vedas , Upanishads ,Puranas ,Stotras etc. Which mentions about unity in diversity of Bharat Varsha of that time  and about  divine God Dispenser of the destiny of India.**?

Comment: @Yogi - Yes  correct , i know that and same thought also came in my mind while asking the question.But since we don't know  exactly what region is assumed by puranas as Bharat Varsha.My question assumes it's mostly indian sub-continent and India.And expects answer mentioning this region only.

Comment: There is another question about "Supreme divine God or Parabrahma who is the dispenser of the destiny of Bharat varsha" and Brhaman is the concept of Upanishadas.Thats the reason of TAG  "Upanishads"

Comment: The Jana Gana Mana song doesn't discuss unity in diversity as far as I know.  So why are you asking about unity in diversity?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - The "Jana Gana Mana" Anthem is used as a example ,to show the various regions ie. Symbolically diversity. Like there are various kandas in Skanda purana eg.Shayadri kanda, Kedāra Khaṇḍa etc .So they were various regions in ancient times.But now those names do not exsist.So used as example text.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - And also to  show  the "Bharat Bhagya Vidhata" concept.The word "ucchalajaladhitaraṅga" meaning - As waves in ocean are not different from ocean itself.Thats the message of unity.

Comment: Ekam Sat Vipra Bahudha Vadanti - Truth is One, men call It by various names - Rg Veda 1.164.46

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Namaste , Yes very correct. But my question is not related to knowladge or truth.But concept of unity in various different geographical regions of Bharat Varsha.ie.there were vatious "Sangha Rajaya's before , This unity concept was brought by "Chanakya" also.Pls.see - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_period